# non-research level algorithm problems

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm taking an undergrad course based on Cormen, which includes allot of "prove the correctness of the algorithm" type problems.  These are generally not research level problems, so they don't belong on the cstheory site according to it's faq.  So where do they go?  For example, [I posted an answer to a question from Skeina's Algorithm Design Manual on programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/186081/73652), and got the comment that it belongs on cstheory, but like I said above, the cstheory faq clear states that it's only for research level problems.

What's the right home for these types of questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, your questions would be right at home on this site.

However, note that you should post *good* questions only. Some problematic types of questions are

- "Please solve this exercise for me."
- "Please check my proof/solution."

A good question focuses on a specific problem (e.g. "I got this far with this exercise, and now I am stuck. I feel like A should work but I fail because of B. What is going on?") and should allow rich answers, i.e. not only "yes" or "no".

In summary, your questions are welcome here as long as you make sure to make an effort yourself before asking and directing the reader to your specific problem.

Comment: Does the question I linked in the OP belong on this site?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes The topic is appropriate, but not the quality of the question. All you did was to dump the text of the exercise. You also need to give a little bit of context (so we know what background level to assume in answers) and **tell us what you tried**. Please read our [homework policy](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy/470#470) (whether or not this is an assignment that was given to you in a school setting).

Comment: @Gilles As part of the OP I answered my own question with a full answer, according to the Q/A "share your knowledge" aspect of the site.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes If it's *knowledge*, that's fine. If it's "I have an idea, let's see whether somebody finds a mistake" it's not fine because, in all likelihood, few people will read a long, complex post like that without motivation (causing any error of yours to stand there as alleged fact).